# Solving $ U=\frac{2\cdot λ_g}{\pi\cdot B+d_f}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{\pi\cdot B}{d_f}+1\right) $ for $d_f$

Tags: logarithms

Can anyone help me solve this equation to isolate $d_f$?

$$ U=\frac{2\cdot λ_g}{\pi\cdot B+d_f}\cdot \ln\left(\frac{\pi\cdot B}{d_f}+1\right) $$

[(original equation from ISO13370)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lg0UW.png)

I can get the values from the natural log with inverse log, but then I'm still left with the $d_f$ term in the other part of the equation.

Help please!!!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Since $d_f$ is both inside and outside the logarithm, the equation is [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) and resists algebraic solution. Numerical methods (or perhaps special functions) are required.

Comment: Thanks @Blue. I've been staring at this all afternoon, and your response helps me realise I'm not going mad! this is for a coding project, so won't be hard to get the code to iterate through possible answers.

Comment: Is $d_f >0$ or not ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, df should be > 0.

Comment: Have a look at my answer and, please, answer my last question. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing notations : $a=2\lambda_g$, $b=\pi B$, $d_f=x$, $y=U$, you want to solve for $x$ the equation
$$y=\frac a {b+x}\log \left(\frac{b}{x}+1\right)$$ where (having read the $ISO 13370$ norm) I suppose that all $(a,b,c,x,y)$ are positive.

Now, let $x=\frac b z$ to make
$$\frac b a y=\frac{z }{z+1}\log (z+1) < \log(z+1)$$ and the rhs is a nice, smooth, increasing function. So we have an upper bound of the solution
$$z_0=e^{\frac{b }{a}y}-1$$

Now, starting with this guess $z_0=(e^k-1)$, start Newton iteration for the function
$$f(z)=\frac{z }{z+1}\log (z+1)-k\qquad \text{where} \quad k=\frac b a y$$
$$f'(z)=\frac{z+\log (z+1)}{(z+1)^2}$$
that is to say
$$z_{n+1}=z_n-\frac {f(z_n)}{f'(z_n)}$$
It would converge very fast.

Let me try for $k=12.34$, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & z_n \\
 0 & 228660.9521 \\
 1 & 228673.2914 \\
 2 & 228673.2918
\end{array}
\right)$$
For the case where $z$ is small compared to $1$  (so $k$), $z_0$ could be too far from the solution. So, using series expansion close to $z=0$,
$$k=z^2-\frac{3 z^3}{2}+\frac{11 z^4}{6}-\frac{25 z^5}{12}+\frac{137 z^6}{60}-\frac{49
   z^7}{20}+\frac{363 z^8}{140}+O\left(z^9\right)$$ and using series reversion
$$z=\sqrt{k}+\frac{3 k}{4}+\frac{47 k^{3/2}}{96}+\frac{7 k^2}{24}+\frac{14939
   k^{5/2}}{92160}+\frac{49 k^3}{576}+\frac{876719
   k^{7/2}}{20643840}+O\left(k^4\right)$$ Trying for $k=0.1234$, the above truncated series would give $z=0.470552$ while the exact solution is $z=0.470558$.

Comment: Amazing. Thanks so much this Claude - really helpful. I've implemented an iterative approach in the Python programming language, but this will be much faster.

Comment: @SamArcher. You are welcome ! Please tell me if $k$ is supposed to be large or small (give me an order of magnitude. I think that we could have a close-to-explicit formula.